# Time evolution generated by grand canonical ensemble

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, greens-functions

Our professor in condensed matter physics derived a differential equation for the zero temperature Greens functions. In the derivation he makes use of the Heisenberg equation of motion to find the derivative of the particle field operator, i.e.

$i\partial _t \Psi(x, t) = [\Psi, H].$

Here $H = H_{s} - \mu N$, with the "normal" Hamiltonian describing the system $H_s$, chemical potential $\mu$ and the number operator $N$.

Why is this reasonable? In some situations it might come handy to make the above redefinition but why would the the chemical potential part impact the time evolution of the system on the microscopic level?

The greens function are introduced as $G = -i<T\{\Psi(x,t)\Psi^\dagger(x',t')\}>$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases of interest adding term $\mu N = \mu\sum_k c_k^\dagger c_k$ merely shifts the energy of the particles:
$$\sum_k E_kc_k^\dagger c_k \rightarrow \sum_k (E_k-\mu)c_k^\dagger c_k.$$
Thus, nothing changes from the point of view of the dynamics. On the other hand, having the evolution operator to coincide with the one in the density matrix used for averaging,
$$\rho = e^{-\beta(H_s-\mu N)},$$
simplifies a lot of math, e.g. when deriving the Lehmann representation, Matsubara expansion, etc.

**Update**
Following the discussion, it is necessary to add a correction: the expositions of the Green's function formalism usually deal with the situations where the number of particles is conserved ($[N, H_s]=0$) or where the particles are created/annihilated in pairs. If the Hamiltonian contains source terms adding odd numbers of particles, it usually requires extension of the formalism, as, e.g., in the case of superfluidity/superconductivity.

Comment: what about the following? Take one mode with energy E and consider the vacuum state $|0>$ and one particle state $|1>$ in this mode. Then construct $|\Psi> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0> + |1>)$ and look at the probability of fnding $|\Psi>(t)$ in the state $|\Psi>$, which gives $p = \cos^2(\frac{E-\mu}{2}t)$. So in this context absorbing $\mu$ into $H$ has an impact on the dynamics.

Comment: @user2224350 Do you mean a one-particle excitation where a particle is moved from one state to another or an excitation where the $N+1$th particle is added?

Comment: I take $|1> = c^\dagger_k|0>$, with $k$ being the specific mode with energy $E$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I mean that, if $\hat{N}|0\rangle = \mathcal{N}|0\rangle$ then $\hat{N}|1\rangle = \hat{N}c_k^\dagger|0\rangle =c_k^\dagger(\hat{N}+1)|0\rangle = (\mathcal{N}+1)c_k^\dagger|0\rangle =  (\mathcal{N}+1)|1\rangle$, whereas the averaging is restricted to the states with a fixed number of particles, unless you have particle sources in the Hamiltonian. The latter situation actually happens in superconductivity and superfluidity and requires some modification of the formalism. Without sources the only possible exitations are of type  $c_k^\dagger c_q|0\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, but $|0>$ actually contains zero particles, s.t. $|\Psi(t)> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0> + e^{-i(E-\mu)t}|1>)$

Comment: 1. In condensed matter $|0\rangle$ is the ground state of a many-particle system. It contains $N$ particles, but zero excitations. 2. If your Hamiltonian does not have a source term, the states like the one that you suggest are impossible. In condensed matter excitations are formed by moving an electron from below the Fermi level to above the Fermi level, in QFT they are often created in pairs (e.g., electron and positron) or have zero $\mu$ (e.g., photons).

Comment: Well yes, regarding 1., I took the "real" vacuum just for simplicity. The above argument would still hold, as an overall phase could be factored out.. Anyways, I see your point. As long as no superpositions of states of different particle number are relevant, $H$ an be defined in the above way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because $\mu$ determines the equilibrium particle density and having a lot of particles about  definitely affects the behaviour of an interacting  system.

Comment: Well, but H_s does already depend on the amount of particles. Furthermore $\mu$ determines the equilibrium state, why would this change the dynamics?

Comment: Where in $H_s$ is the particle density specified?